# Play mp3 according choice of button on main page

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to realize app which will have few slides. How to do it I've understood. Now On first page I have created two buttons.

First button means that next slide by clicking flipper forward will play mp3 file with MAN's voice.
 Second button means that next slide by clicking flipper forward will play mp3 file with WOMAN's voice...

```
myOption1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option1);
        myOption2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option2);

    myOption1.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);
    myOption2.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);


    myOption1.setChecked(true);
    myOption2.setChecked(false);
```

...

```
RadioButton.OnClickListener myOptionOnClickListener =
            new RadioButton.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View vmw) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (myOption2.isChecked()== true){
                    myOption1.setChecked(false);
                    myOption1.isClickable();
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                            "Option 1 : " + myOption1.isChecked() + "\n"+
                            "Option 2 : " + myOption2.isChecked(),

                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    myOption1.setChecked(true);
                    myOption2.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                            "Option 1 : " + myOption1.isChecked() + "\n"+
                            "Option 2 : " + myOption2.isChecked(),

                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
```

1. OnclickListener changes bool when click second button, but when press ferst button for man's voice - nothing changes!!! Option2 becomes true, but it must become false if I check first button...((((

2.How can I get result of this choice on the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onClick(View vmw) use the vmw(view) to get myOptions(RadioButton) like :

```
RadioButton myOption = (RadioButton)vmw;
```

then check the conditions. Please try this and reply.

Comment: I have decided to do such thing, and now I have myoption1 or myoption2 clicked true....

Comment: if (myOption2.isChecked()== true){
                    myOption1.setChecked(false);
                    myOption1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: by another slide you mean an Activity right? If yes then pass the the state(checked/notchecked) to that activity via intent and check state in that activity. According to the state received apply your logic.

Comment: No, I have realized all slidex in XML by flipper... Thanks, my problem is decided by.......

Comment: if (myOption1.isChecked()== true){
              mp_file = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.zh_01); 
                    mp_file.start();
                    return;
             }else {
              mp_file = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.m_01); 
                    mp_file.start();
                    return;
    }